# 'SharePointTheme' does not contain a definition for 'customtheme'

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, modern-experience, theme, office-dev-pnp

I am trying to apply custom theme to my site collection but getting below error while applying:

> Error CS0117  'SharePointTheme' does not contain a definition for 'customtheme'

Below is my code line:

```
var customtheme = "Custom Theme";
Web web = ctx.Web;
//ctx.Credentials = cred;
ctx.Load(web);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
ThemeManager.ApplyTheme(ctx.Web, OfficeDevPnP.Core.Enums.SharePointTheme.customtheme)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this reference [SharePointTheme.cs](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Enums/SharePointTheme.cs), `SharePointTheme` enum has below values only:

```
namespace OfficeDevPnP.Core.Enums
{
    public enum SharePointTheme
    {
        Blue,
        Orange,
        Red,
        Purple,
        Green,
        Gray,
        DarkYellow,
        DarkBlue,
        Teal
    }
}
```

You are receiving this error because there is no definition `customtheme` in above enum.

---

Also, check this documentation for [applying a theme using CSOM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-csom),

> There's currently no supported CSOM API to programmatically apply a theme to a specific site. For information on applying custom themes to individual site collections see [SharePoint site design and site script overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview)

---

Check other overloading methods for `ApplyTheme()` method at [ThemeManager.cs](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/deba8844ac45fa3e481ab11c66dfa4cd85489b4d/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Utilities/Themes/ThemeManager.cs) which might help you with applying custom theme.